# Call the function overrided in the override function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here is a code from a tuto with room. But room is not the question here. (I am a beginner in kotlin). I have a question about this code.

```
const val TABLE_NAME = "Articles"
​
@Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
class Article() : Comparable<Article> {
​
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0
    var title: String? = null
    var date: Date? = null
    var description: String? = null
    var image: String? = null
    var isRead: Boolean = false
​
    override fun compareTo(other: Article): Int {
        return other.date!!.compareTo(this.date)
    }
​
    constructor(title: String, date: Date, description: String, image: String, id: Long, read: Boolean) : this() {
        this.title = title
        this.date = date
        this.description = description
        this.image = image
        this.id = id
        this.isRead = read
    }
}
```

I see a call to a function compareTo in the override compareTo.

Is the compareTo function in the return is the original none overrided function ?

Thanks.

Comment: well no, the `other.date.compareTo()` will simply call `Date::compareTo()`

Comment: All classes/objects have some implementation of `compareTo()` or they inherit it from the `Object` class. So unless `Date` has a overriden implementation, it will call `Object`'s `compareTo`

Comment: Perfect. I have understood. Thanks ! If you want you can add this answer and I’ll vote for you.

Comment: fair enough, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no - the `other.date.compareTo()` will simply call the `Date::compareTo()` method instead of your `Article::compareTo()`.

Comment: "All classes/objects have some implementation of compareTo, or they inherit it from Object which just checks their references (i think?)." You are confusing it with `equals`; `Object` doesn't have `compareTo`, and so not all classes do.

Comment: yes, indeed. my mistake. Only `Comparable` objects (classes implementing the Comparable interface) have them, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Or someone could declare their own `compareTo` method without implementing `Comparable`, of course.

Comment: feel free to propose an edit, i admit - i'm kinda too lazy atm.

Comment: Just removed the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "original non-overridden function" to call here. If there were it could be called as `super.compareTo(...)`. You can see some examples in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#calling-the-superclass-implementation). `override` is also used when implementing an abstract function and that's what happens for `Article`.